# Foreach with data from two tables laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am currently building a project / learning laravel.

i have two databaes with one colomn in both tables with teh same unique value.

in my blade page i have a foreach which loops through the first table but i cannot figure out how to get it to correctly bring the second table data with it etc.

here is the code.

my resturants model.

```
class Restaurant extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $table = 'restaurants';

public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('restaurant_id');
}
```

Reviews model

```
class Review extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'reviews';


public $review;

public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('restaurant_id');
}
```

blade foreach loop

```
 @foreach(array_slice($restaurants, 0, 5) as $restaurants)

{{$restaurant[0]->restaurant_id}}}

{{$reviews= Review::find(1)->where('restaurant_id', '=', $restaurant[0]->restaurant_id)->get()}}

@emdforeach
```

the controller passes data fine so ill exclude that.

i am trying to get the relevant review to pass along with the restaurant object etc.

any ideas?

if you see any typos excuse as i had to retype on a laptop and desktop code is good :)

UPDATE

Thank you very much for your help, after your explanation i understand it so thanks :)

none the less when i try it i get Trying to get property of non-object.

Here is the updated code

Restaurant model

```
class Restaurant extends Eloquent implements UserInterface,     RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'restaurants';


public $restaurant;



public function reviews() 
 {
return $this->hasOne('Review', 'restaurant_id', );
}
```

In my view

v {{ dd($restaurants->reviews) }}

this gives me Trying to get property of non-object.

$restaurants works perfectly just not with reviews? i can dd it and see the 5 objects in the array

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of a `$restaurant`, you can get a collection of it's reviews like this:

```
$reviews = $restaurant->reviews;
```

Since this is a many to many relationship it returns a collection, and you can now `@foreach` over this collection as well:

```
@foreach(array_slice($restaurants, 0, 5) as $restaurants)

    {{ $restaurant[0]->restaurant_id }}

    @foreach($restaurant->reviews as $review)
        {{ $review->rating }}
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

The `reviews` property exists on the restaurant model because you defined this method:

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('restaurant_id');
}
```

Accessing related properties in this manner is similar to the first example given in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one).  If you want to look at the source and see whats going on, [here](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L2561) is the function that is called whenever you access a model property that isn't defined specifically in the class (i.e. not `$fillable` or `$guarded`, but any of the data attributes, relations accessed like attributes, etc).

If instead you had a `Chef` model and a database structure where a restaurant could have many chefs and you defined this method in your restaurant model:

```
public function chefs() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('Chef');
}
```

Then you could get a listing of all of the chefs at a restaurant like this:

```
$chefs = $restaurant->chefs;
```

You can also call the method directly, if for instance you wanted to add further restrictions to the query:

```
$chefsNamedBob = $restaurant->chefs()->where('name', '=', 'Bob')->get();
```

Notice that, when called this way, you will have to call `->get()` or `->first()` as well, which is different when attempting to access relations via a property of an instance rather than as a method on an instance.  This is because when you call the method, the query has not been executed yet (that's what `get()` does).  When you access the relationship as a property, by the time you receive the results the query is already executed (meaning there's no more time left for SQL to do the filtering for you).

**Update**

I also notice that you have an error in your relations.  You define your restaurant to review relationship like this:

```
return $this->hasMany('restaurant_id');
```

The first argument to the `hasMany` function is *not* a column name.  In general the function signature for a relationship function is this:

```
return $this->hasOne('ModelClassName', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

See the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) for more information.  If you are following the eloquent conventions (plural table names, id as primary key, foreign key names are correct) then you can use a shortcut and just specify the model class name:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('ModelClassName');
```

Which is a great reason to follow convention.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, after your explanation i understand it so thanks :)

Comment: any ideas about this?